Computations in coordinates of Hamiltonian vector fields
I just need someone to snap me out of a (hopefully small) misunderstanding: in p.574 of (the 2nd edition of) Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds it is written that a Hamiltonian vector field $X_f$ of a function $f$ is written, in any Darboux coordinates, as
$$\sum_i \left( a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + b^i\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}\right)$$
for some coefficients $(a_i,b_i)$ to be determined.
Here's what I don't get: if $X_f$ gives a tangent vector at each point, and since the $\partial/\partial x^i$ form a basis at each point of the manifold, wouldn't $X_f$ take instead the form
$$\sum_i \left( a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)$$
for some coefficients $(a_i)$ to be determined.

This fragment of the book refers to symplectic manifolds, which are of even dimension. Darboux coordinates are coordinates $(x^1, x^2, \ldots, x^n, y^1, y^2, \ldots, y^n)$ such that symplectic form has representation $\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n dx^i \land dy^i$.
So this is just some notation convenience. You could write $x^{n + i} = y^i$ and give coordinate representation as you stated, but the author probably has something in mind when giving this representation.

It may be that your confusion arises from the case when the symplectic manifold (the phase space) is the cotangent bundle $T^* M$ of some other manifold $M$ (the configuration space).
Suppose $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold with (position) coordinates $x^i$, so that the vectors $\partial/\partial x^i$ form a basis of the tangent space $T_a M$ at each point $a \in M$.
Then $X_f$ is not a vector field on $M$ but on the cotangent bundle $T^* M$, of dimension $2n$, where $x^i$ and $y^i$ are coordinates (positions and momenta) and the vectors $\partial/\partial x^i$ and $\partial/\partial y^i$ form a basis of the tangent space $T_{(a,b)} T^* M$ at each point $(a,b) \in T^* M$.
So when you write “$X_f$ gives a tangent vector at each point” and “the $\partial/\partial x^i$ form a basis at each point of the manifold”, it sounds to me like you are actually confusing points of two different manifolds: $T^* M$ in the first case, and $M$ in the second case.
